# How to disable Block Ack in Aruba 11n Access point?

Tags: wifi

is there some method to disable Block Ack feature in Aruba AP keeping 11n intact?

Comment: You would better ask this on http://serverfault.com/ or http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/. You can use your http://stackoverflow.com/ account for this, linking it to these communities too. Go to the site, upper right click on "join this community".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from Aruba community so updating the same here for future reference :

From Cmd line :

`(ArubaController) #configure terminal wlan ht-ssid-profile {profile_name} (ArubaController)(High-throughput SSID profile "{profile_name}") #no mpdu-agg`

From the GUI the change can be made from

`Configuration > AP Group > Wireless Lan > VAP Profile > SSID > High-throughput SSID (advanced) > MPDU Aggregation unchecked.`